# No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"tours", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncontroller

I have been following a tutorial http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Although following each step but changing Article to Tour (I am new to RoR) - but now when trying to edit a specific tour the message comes up with:

ActionController::UrlGenerationError at /tours/3/edit
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"tours", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id] 
- with better errors it points to my edit.html.erb

**edit.html.erb**

```
<h1>Editing TOURS</h1>

<%= form_for :tour, url: tour_path(@tour), method: :patch do |f| %>

  <% if @tour.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@tour.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
        this tour from being saved:
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @tour.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>

<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', tours_path %>
```

routes.rb

```
        Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action
         tours GET    /tours(.:format)          tours#index
               POST   /tours(.:format)          tours#create
      new_tour GET    /tours/new(.:format)      tours#new
     edit_tour GET    /tours/:id/edit(.:format) tours#edit
          tour GET    /tours/:id(.:format)      tours#show
               PATCH  /tours/:id(.:format)      tours#update
               PUT    /tours/:id(.:format)      tours#update
               DELETE /tours/:id(.:format)      tours#destroy
  static_about GET    /static/about(.:format)   static#about
static_contact GET    /static/contact(.:format) static#contact
          root GET    /                         static#home
```

**tours_controller.rb**

```
class ToursController < ApplicationController

    def index
    @tours = Tour.all
    end

    def new
    @tour = Tour.new
    end

    def show
    @tour = Tour.find(params[:id])
    end

    def create
    @tour = Tour.new(tour_params)

    if @tour.save
        redirect_to @tour
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

    def update
      @tour = Tour.find(params[:id])

      if @tour.update(tour_params)
        redirect_to @tour
      else
        render 'edit'
      end
    end

    private
        def tour_params
            params.require(:tour).permit(:title, :text)
        end
    end
```

--
All my other CRUD actions work besides the edit action.
Any help and sure it is something basic I am missing..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be an edit action in your tours controller

```
def edit
   @tour = Tour.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: again thanks, my next step is to add the tours to a user/host using devise